# Tag Badge Progess not updating

Tags: bug

If I configure my profile to show "Next tag badge" in the Reputation widget in my profiles Activity, this progess is not tracked.

The value stays the same for days at time. Only by re-selecting the tag I want to track will the values adjust to the score gained in the meantime.